# background image issue in firefox mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

This is the link to the website I am doing HTML/CSS of 
http://test33-jg-us-mb-en.apsww.net/index.php/ex-team-22/jewelry-affiliate-program
on every mobile browser it works fine but in firefox mobile the background image in tabs do not show how it is in actual and also the alignment on Join now button is not correct. Can anyone please help me out with that how I can fix the background issue and how I can use exceptions for firefox mobile to set the join now alignment. Thanks in advance

The site is static for both pc and mobile resolution both.

Regards,
IMMAD

Answer (score 0):

Help us reproduce the background-image error.

For the **Join Now** alignment, add style `margin: 0px auto;` before your `margin-bottom` style.

Comment: Hey Kabir thanks for the answer, I think you didn't get my point mate. If I apply the style you mentioned above then the join now button will be in the middle. For the alignment of the button is correct in almost every browser only in firefox mobile browser the text goes a bit lower and only in firefox the it does not shows the images properly which are in the background.
Let me make it clear the issues are in the mobile browsers and not in browsers for PC.